# Can I connect my honda 150cc bike head lamp to the battery directly? Will this damage my battery?

Tags: honda

Headlight is dim if I go slow. If I connect the head light directly to the battery is there any problem?

Comment: Welcome to the site. There is very little information here to be able to give a good answer. Please [edit] your question to include more details. How old is this bike? When did the problem start? Has this always been a problem?

Comment: Might want to check voltage at the battery and voltage at the light.  If there is a significant difference, trace the wire back and try to find where the voltage drops at.  There could be an issue with your alternator / generator where it is not producing enough voltage at lower RPM.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that and I would suggest using a fuse.

However, unless there is a poor connection / fault in the existing wiring or switch it won't make any difference.

If the headlight is brighter then you need to find out why : a poor contact in the switch, loose connections, corroded wires, bad earth points, loose earth points, any one or more of these can be the cause of a dim headlight.

One other thought is has someone put the wrong voltage bulb into the headlight?